# Task 'Publish Artifact' works wrong TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I recently had problems generating the publish in the task 'Publish Artifact' of TFS2015, this was already configured to be published in a file share and the route that was assigned to it worked perfectly, due to infrastructure issues I had to change the file share path which since then has started to generate intermittency and creation of erroneous routes for my continuous integration process. I mean: the build is generated, runs well, the publish artifact is generated, "runs well", and gives us a build Succeeded in theory, but at the time of seeing the compiled ones they are not or another folder has been generated, that is to say if I wanted my folder to be 1.0.0, create folders like: 1.0. or 1.0.0. or simply does not publish.

To advance doubts:

- Yes, the fileshare is in the base format (\ Myfile \ share).
- Yes, I have access to the file share from the machine that is being compiled.
- The file share is the same only the access alias is changed, that is to say, step from \ MyFile \ Share to \ Myfile2 \ Share (I do not know if this is the cause).

To summarize, the build is generated and gives us an Ok but nevertheless leaves it in the requested directories sometimes if and sometimes not, I appreciate your help.

Comment: How did you set for the path to create the folder like 1.0.0? Do you use the variables in the path? What's that mean for " sometimes if and sometimes not,"? What's the result if you set `Artifact Type` to **server** ? Could you please share the settings of the `Publish build Artifact` task, and the build logs when it has issue. Or you can have a try with this setting: `\\my\share\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)`

Comment: That´s right , I'm using variables in the path, I've set a variable called "Version" and in the path I put it like this:
\\my\path\$(Version)
of course i i always set the variable when I start a Build.

In the other hand it was a typo, I mean "sometimes works some sometimes don't" 

I really need yo use this artifact Type as : File Share
the config is:

Path to publish: "C:\agent\work\42\s\Inco\bin\x64\Release"
Artifact Name:   "Inco"
Articaft Type:     "File share"
Path:                  "\\Cen-Clusfs01\pru-ins\mp\2017\$(Version)\"

As I said before the buid work fine supposedly

Comment: Seems the problem is caused by the custom variable `$(Version)`.  How did you set the `$(Version)` variable? Whatever I suggest you use the pre-defined variables such as the default `$(Build.BuildNumber)` to check if that works for you.

Comment: I create the variable $(Version) in the tab variables, this configuration worked perfectly for a year, the problem started when the publish path change, for example: the path was \\cen200\shares\.......... this was change for \\Cen-Clusfs01\......; i don't know if this is an important fact, the build is deleting the last character of the variable "Version" for example: if i set version: 123 creates the folder 12 (sometimes), 60% of the time works fine, i really don't now what could be the problem.